# how to use bash script to mask certain field of a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, unix

the file is a comma separated file like:

```
    hue,1,123456,wow,hai
    heu,2,654321,waw,hey
    uhe,3,001100,iwi,hel
    euh,4,119988,qaq,hal
```

and we want to mask the third column with our own method:

```
0->9
1->8
2->7
3->6
4->5
5->4
6->3
7->2
8->1
9->0
```

thus after the script we should get something like:

```
    hue,1,876543,wow,hai
    heu,2,345678,waw,hey
    uhe,3,998899,iwi,hel
    euh,4,880011,qaq,hal
```

Comment: @Inian yes we can do that

Answer (score 0):

try following and let me know if this helps you(created in GNU awk).

```
awk  -F, 'function change(field){num=split(field, array,"");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){gsub(/.*/,9-array[i],array[i]);new=new?new array[i]:array[i]};$3=new;new=""} change($3) 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hue 1 876543 wow hai
heu 2 345678 waw hey
uhe 3 998899 iwi hel
euh 4 880011 qaq hal
```

***EDIT:*** A generic solution where you could change values inside BEGIN block of array named array and could make use of any substitutions you want and you could more and more values which you want to substitute too in it.

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN{
  num=split("0-9,1-8,2-7,3-6,4-5,5-4,6-3,7-2,8-1,9-0",array,",");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    split(array[i],array1,"-");
    value[array1[1]]=array1[2]
}
}
function change(field){
  num=split(field, a,"");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    new=new?(a[i] in value?new value[a[i]]:new a[i]):(a[i] in value?value[a[i]]:a[i])
};
  $3=new;
  new=""
}
change($3)
1
' OFS=,   Input_file
```

Comment: you script is good. While what I ask for is the script that I can custom the method. So your script only works for the case that the number decrease by 1. But if i want something like

    0-2
    1-4
    2-6....

it wont work for sure.

Comment: @BeyondTryingToCode, kindly check my EDIT solution now and let me know if this helps you, there you could add/edit any values which you want to substitute, let me know on same.